# Remove event listeners from all nodes except

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to build a utility function that follows the following criteria:

- (selectors: string[]) => void
- Removes all event listeners from the page, except for on elements matching the selectors provided in the array
- **Doesn't** use the `getEventListeners` function in Chrome's API

Some important factors:

- I don't know or have access to the functions that were passed in when adding and event listener to each of these elements, so `removeEventListener` is out of the question
- Ideally, I don't want to inject a script prior to the page's scripts running to override the addEventListener method. But if that's necessary, then so be it.

Here's an example of something I've already tried:

```
// only using "getEventListeners" because I'm testing this in devtools
getEventListeners(document.querySelector('#server')) // has event listeners

const removeAllEventListenersExcept = (selectors = []) => {
    // loop through all dom nodes
    for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('*')]) {
        // if it matches one of our selectors, skip it
        // this gets logged, so why is the listener still being removed?
        if (selectors.some((s) => node.matches(s))) return console.log('hi');
        
        // else, make a clone of the node (which removes its event listeners)
        const clone = node.cloneNode(true)
        // replace the one in the dom with the new clone
        node.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, node)
    }
}

removeAllEventListenersExcept(['#server'])

getEventListeners(document.querySelector('#server')) // no event listeners on it
```

Here is my implementation using `getEventListeners` that works nicely (focusing on click listeners); however, once again, I can't use this:

```
const getAllWithClickListeners = () => {
    const elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
    elems.push(window)
    elems.push(document)
    const listeners = []
    elems.forEach((elem) => {
        const result = getEventListeners(elem)
        if (Object.values(result).length && result.click) {
            listeners.push({
                node: elem,
                ...result
            })
        }
    })
    return listeners;
}

const removeAllClickListenersExcept = (selectors = []) => {
    const allWithClickListeners = getAllWithClickListeners()
    for (const { node, click } of allWithClickListeners) {
        if(selectors.some((s) => node.matches(s))) return;
        for (const listener of click) { // click === array of the node's click listeners
            node.removeEventListener('click', listener.listener, listener.useCapture)
            node.removeAttribute('onclick')
        }
    }
}
removeAllClickListenersExcept(['#server'])
```

All suggestions welcome. I've been scouring the internet for ideas, so please don't snipe my question just 'cause the title is similar to other questions. Even my project manager is stumped.

Comment: You will definitely have to inject your own script before any other code on the page runs to override `addEventListener` so you can spy on functions passed in, otherwise `removeEventListener` won't work

Comment: @CertainPerformance This must certainly be possible without `removeEventListener`. Cloning a node removes its listeners.

Comment: I guess you could do that, but that'd also break the functionality of many scripts that depend on having a persistent reference to an element currently in the DOM. Is that really not a dealbreaker?

Comment: @CertainPerformance True that. So would you say to just override the addEventListener prototype and block it from happening on any nodes not approved in the array?

Comment: If you want to prevent the listeners from being added in the first place, sure, yeah, that'd be relatively simple. If you need to remove them only on demand at some point in the future, it's a bit harder, but not by much